# How do I prevent the Windows 8.1 news app from downloading in the background?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

Every so often, the Windows 8.1 News app spawns a background task that locks up my internet for a minute or so while it downloads articles. Very annoying when I'm in an RDP session, or trying to play an online game.

The Charms -> Settings -> Permissions menu doesn't have an "Allow this app to run in the background" slider, I don't see anything related under "Start-up" in the task manager, nor in Services.

I don't need news updated in the background, how can I turn this off?

Comment: Right-click on the News live tile and you can turn the live tile off, which I believe should disable the background updates.

Comment: That appears to have fixed it. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to disable the live tile (and thus the background updates) by right-clicking on the News tile from the Start screen, and then select "Turn live tile off".

Comment: In my case it was still downloading crap after this.